# Issue in resizing the whole html page to fit into standard pdf size when converting using ITextsharp,

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i Have an issue with conversation of html page to pdf format using Itextsharp dll.
I have an aspx page where html is defined in percentage to fit full screen only we have font size set to 24 px,the issue which i am facing is that the entire page is not able to fit  into A4 size pdf format as the html is getting truncated from right after conversation to half,please help with any property available that will make it to fit in A4 pdf format.
Note:when i do print preview or save using right click the text shrinks and able to save,i am expecting same kind of behaviour in html to pdf conversion using Itextsharp dll.

Please find aspx.cs

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

//Document pdfDoc = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(2000,2000), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);


         //   PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
           // pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(sr.ReadToEnd()));
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            writer.ClearTextWrap();

            pdfDoc.Open();
            var style = new StyleSheet();
            style.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", "8px");
            HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            htmlworker.SetStyleSheet(style);
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
                                           "filename=sample.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
            string close = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                                window.returnValue = true;
                                window.close();
                                </script>";
            base.Response.Write(close);
```

Comment: Which version of iText? Also, could you replace `HTMLWorker` with `XMLWorker`? Because `HTMLWorker` is deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: The code is strange because `HTMLWorker` and `XMLWorkerHelper` are used in the same snippet (which makes no sense). The question is strange because it says that content is truncated, which is impossible: iText creates new pages when content doesn't fit. Also, the OP is comparing behavior that requires user input with behavior that is done by a machine. I assume that the OP didn't read the documentation, because there's an example that does more or less what he needs in iText in Action - Second Edition.